# Potsgres SQL: select timestamp prior to max timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, timestamp, max

I have a table in Postgres with timestamps:

```
timestamp
2022-01-01 00:52:53
2022-01-01 00:57:12
...
2022-02-13 11:00:31
2022-02-13 16:45:10
```

How can I select the timestamp closest to max timestamp? Meaning, I want the timestamp 2022-02-13 11:00:31.

I am looking for something like `max(timestamp)-1` so I can do on a recurring basis. Thank you

Comment: You'll need to define corner cases: can there be duplicates? Null values? Just one row or no row? What to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query might meet your requirements:

```
SELECT MAX(date_col) FROM test WHERE date_col < (SELECT MAX(date_col) from test);
```

See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/3926)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    rank() over(order by timestamp desc) as rk
  from t
) x
where rk = 2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7r7bymbPf7F8iLEytFXyDX/0).